# Flushing cache when DMAing directly to user memory

Tags: caching, linux-device-driver, virtual-memory

I have written a driver whose purpose is allow a userspace program to pin its pages and get the physical addresses for them.

Specifically, I do this with a call to `get_user_pages_fast` in my kernel module.

For reference, the source code to this module can be found here: https://github.com/UofT-HPRC/mpsoc_drivers/tree/master/pinner

Using `/dev/mem` (and yes, my kernel does allow unsafe `/dev/mem` accesses) I have confirmed that the physical addresses are correct.

However, I have some external hardware (an AXI DMA in an FPGA, to be precise) which is not working, and it looks like it might be a cache coherency problem. On lines 329-337 of the above linked code, I do this: (in this code, cm.usr_buf is a user virtual address)

```
//Find the VMA containing the user's buffer
struct vm_area_struct *vma = find_vma(current->mm, (unsigned long)cmd.usr_buf);
if (!vma) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "pinner: unrecognized user virtual address\n");
    return -EINVAL;
}
flush_cache_range(vma, (unsigned long) cmd.usr_buf, (unsigned long) cmd.usr_buf + cmd.usr_buf_sz);
```

This doesn't appear to help. I have also tried the more general `flush_cache_mm` function.

Is there a correct way to flush the cache of user pages?

Answer (score 1):

I tried a different API for flushing the cache. Laurent Pinchard gave a talk called "[Mastering the DMA and IOMMU APIs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n07zPcbdX_w)", and in it he explains that the functions in `<asm/cacheflush.h>` shouldn't be used. Instead, you can use things like `dma_map_sg` and `dma_unmap_sg` when pinning user memory. I took a quick look in the kernel sources, and these functions eventually call assembly routines specific to each architecture, which are possibly responsible for disabling the cache in certain memory regions.

Also, `dma_sync_sg_for_cpu` and `dma_sync_sg_for_device` can be used to force cache flushes if you try to access the memory between DMA transfers.

I rewrote my kernel driver to use these functions, and it works.